# Realtime database CRUD Error (android stuido / firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I open my **app** at the instant he close and tell me on my test device and the **app** crash.

Here is my `LOGCAT` error codes:

```
      05-16 13:34:02.324 25606-25606/? E/Zygote: v2
      05-16 13:34:02.325 25606-25606/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
      05-16 13:34:04.368 25606-25606/studenty.language.android 
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: studenty.language.android, PID: 25606
      com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class 
      studenty.language.android.User does not define a no-argument 
      constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors 
      are not stripped.
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown 
      Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown 
      Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown 
      Source)
      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
      at studenty.language.android.MainActivity$2.onDataChange 
      (MainActivity.java:81)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown 
      Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown 
      Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown 
      Source)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
      (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Class user code:

```
package studenty.language.android;


public class User {
private String id;
private String name;

public User(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public User(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

It´s because i need to add a default no-argument, but how i can create this default no-argument and how i can implement it on my class User code?

Comment: `Class 
      studenty.language.android.User does not define a no-argument 
      constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors 
      are not stripped`  Ring any bell?

Comment: if I say you the true xD... not because im new in firebase and programming any tip?

Comment: create a empty constructor duh!

Comment: I think  need to define arguments for the class User right? but how i do that?

Comment: Just create a default constructor in `User` class. You can have multiple constructors in a class .

Comment: See the accepted answer of the link @ADM gave.

Comment: and how i can fix it?

Comment: i let you the class user code

Comment: simply update this`public User(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}` to this `public User() {
}`